# Accept "Null" value using COALESCE in update statement in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, coalesce

I have multiple `<forms>` which have 1 form element (say textbox) each. But values of all these elements are in a single MySQL table. These elements can be modified (i.e. Insert/Update/Delete) individually by submitting the respective forms individually. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chandannadig/BjtNY/1218/) fiddle to get a basic idea of the html structure.

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form1" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Form 1</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="element1" maxlength="50" />
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Save Changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>


<form class="form-horizontal" id="form2" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Form 2</label>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="element2" maxlength="50" />
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Save Changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['element1'])){
        if(empty($_POST['element1'])){
            $element1= ''; //Update empty value if $_POST is empty
        }
    else{
        $element1= $_POST['element1']; 
    }
    }
    else{
      $element1= null;  
    }

    if(isset($_POST['element2'])){
        if(empty($_POST['element2'])){
            $element2= ''; //Update empty value if $_POST is empty
        }
    else{
        $element2= $_POST['element2']; 
    }
    }
    else{
      $element2= null;  
    }

    $sql_update = "UPDATE element_table SET element1=COALESCE(NULLIF('" . mysql_real_escape_string($element1) . "',''), element1), element2=COALESCE(NULLIF('" . mysql_real_escape_string($element2) . "',''),element2) WHERE id=01";
```

**MySQL Table**

```
________________________________________________________________________________
|   id   |   element1   |   element2   |   element3   |   element4   |   ...   |
________________________________________________________________________________
|   01   |       1      |       2      |       3      |       4      |   ...   |
```

**Requirements**

1. When I submit form 1, $_POST['element2'] is not set, so I do not want to alter element2. Update query modifies only element1.
2. When I submit #form1,

   a. If $_POST['element1'] is not empty, update the value in POST variable.

   b. If $_POST['element1'] **is empty**, then update **null** value to db. i.e. leave the column blank.

**Issue**

Point no.1 and 2.a. are working fine, however I am not able to accomplish point number 2.b. Maybe I am using COALESCE in the wrong way. Can someone please show me how to update an empty value to db while still using COALESCE ? Thank you

P.S. The db design cannot be changed for some reasons which I cannot disclose here.

Answer (score 0):

In the subquery, add `UNION SELECT 'default' LIMIT 1`:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `f1`=(
  SELECT `f2` FROM `table2` WHERE `f3` = 'value'
  UNION SELECT 0
  LIMIT 1
);
```

This is how I just solved a similar issue.